# Kubernetes requests not balanced

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

We've just had an increase in traffic to our kubernetes cluster and I've noticed that of our 6 application pods, 2 of them are seemingly not used very much. `kubectl top pods` returns the following

[image: CPU usage]

You can see of the 6 pods, 4 of them are using more than 50% of the CPU (2 vCPU nodes), but two of them aren't really doing much at all.

Our cluster is setup on AWS, using the ALB ingress controller. The load balancer is configured to use the `Least outstanding requests` rather than `Round robin` in an attempt to balance things out a bit more, but we're still seeing this imbalance.

Is there any way of determining why this is happening, or if indeed it actually is a problem? I'm hoping it's normal behaviour rather than an issue but I'd rather investigate it.

**App deployment config**

This is the configuration of the main application pods. Nothing fancy really

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "app.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "app.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
    app.kubernetes.io/component: web
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.app.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ include "app.fullname" . }}-web

  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/config_maps/app-env-vars.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
      {{- with .Values.podAnnotations }}
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 10 }}
      {{- end }}
      labels:
        {{- include "app.selectorLabels" . | nindent 8 }}
        app.kubernetes.io/component: web
        app: {{ include "app.fullname" . }}-web
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: {{ .Values.serviceAccount.web }}
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - weight: 100
            podAffinityTerm:
              labelSelector:
                matchExpressions:
                - key: app
                  operator: In
                  values:
                  - {{ include "app.fullname" . }}-web
              topologyKey: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Values.image.name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          command:
            - bundle
          args: ["exec", "puma", "-p", "{{ .Values.app.containerPort }}"]
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: {{ .Values.app.containerPort }}
              protocol: TCP
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthcheck
              port: {{ .Values.app.containerPort }}
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 5
            timeoutSeconds: 5
          resources:
            {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
          envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: {{ include "app.fullname" . }}-cm-env-vars

          - secretRef:
              name: {{ include "app.fullname" . }}-secret-rails-master-key

          - secretRef:
              name: {{ include "app.fullname" . }}-secret-db-credentials

          - secretRef:
              name: {{ include "app.fullname" . }}-secret-db-url-app

          - secretRef:
              name: {{ include "app.fullname" . }}-secret-redis-credentials
```

Comment: @Henry that's the result of `kubectl top pods` sorry, not nodes. Each node has the same set of pods - the application and background workers. You can just see the top of one of the background pods in the bottom of the screenshot but they're not currently busy at all

Comment: Have you specified resource limits for pods?

Comment: @slashpai nope. I have on the background worker pods, they're limited to 50% but the app pods have no limit on at all

Comment: Could you share the relevant yaml configs by editing the question?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor sure thing, added the deployment config for the app pods

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a known issue with Kubernetes.
In short, Kubernetes doesn't load balance long-lived TCP connections.
This [excellent article](https://learnk8s.io/kubernetes-long-lived-connections) covers it in details.

The load distribution you service is showing complies exactly with the case.

Comment: Ah that definitely seems to describe the issue! Although, would that still apply when it's running behind an external load balancer? Given we have a basically 1-to-1 mapping of pods-to-nodes, and an external load balancer deciding which node receives the traffic, would this all still apply? Guessing so given the results!

Comment: Well, I would presume an external LB will still have to deal with keep-alive connections (if not, the whole case won't be relevant anymore - but that's hardly possible for any modern app). Unless your LB is capable to manage a pool of persistent connections to all pods and rebalance incoming requests between them, as described in the article, the issue with uneven load distribution will still remain.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the info, definitely seems like the issue