# How does kube-proxy handle persistent connections to a Service between pods?

Tags: kubernetes

I've seen scenarios where requests from one workload, sent to a ClusterIP service for another workload with no affinities set, only get routed to a subset of the associated pods. The Endpoints object for this service does show all of the pod IPs.

I did a little experiment to figure out what is happening.

### Experiment

I set up minikube to have a "router" workload with 3 replicas sending requests to a "backend" workload also with 3 pods. The router just sends a request to the service name like `http://backend`.

I sent 100 requests to the router service via `http://$MINIKUBE_IP:$NODE_PORT`, since it's exposed as a `NodePort` service. Then I observed which backend pods actually handled requests. I repeated this test multiple times.

In most cases, only 2 backend pods handled any requests, with the occasional case where all 3 did. I didn't see any where all requests went to one in these experiments, though I have seen it happen before running other tests in AKS.

This led me to the theory that the router is keeping a persistent connection to the backend pod it connects to. Given there are 3 routers and 3 backends, there's an 11% chance all 3 routers "stick" to a single backend, a 67% chance that between the 3 routers, they stick to 2 of the backends, and a 22% chance that each router sticks to a different backend pod (1-to-1).

Here's one possible combination of router-to-backend connections (out of 27 possible):
[image: three routers sticking to 2 backends]

### Disabling HTTP Keep-Alive

If I use a `Transport` disabling HTTP Keep-Alives in the router's http client, then any requests I make to the router are uniformly distributed between the different backends on every test run as desired.

```golang
client := http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        DisableKeepAlives: true,
    },
}
resp, err := client.Get("http://backend")
```

So the theory *seems* accurate. But here's my question:

- How does the router using HTTP KeepAlive / persistent connections actually result in a single connection between one router pod and one backend pod?

  - There is a `kube-proxy` in the middle, so I'd expect any persistent connections to be between the router pod and `kube-proxy` as well as between `kube-proxy` and the backend pods.
  - Also, when the router does a DNS lookup, it's going to find the **Cluster IP** of the backend service every time, so how can it "stick" to a Pod if it doesn't know the Pod IP?

Using Kubernetes 1.17.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [excellent article](https://learnk8s.io/kubernetes-long-lived-connections) covers your question in detail.
Kubernetes Services indeed do not load balance long-lived TCP connections.

Under the hood Services (in most cases) use `iptables` to distribute connections between pods. But `iptables` wasn't designed as a balancer, it's a firewall. It isn't capable to do high-level load balancing.
As a weak substitution `iptables` can create (or not create) a connection to a certain target with some probability - and thus can be used as L3/L4 balancer. This mechanism is what `kube-proxy` employs to somewhat imitate load balancing.

> **Does iptables use round-robin?**
>
> No, `iptables` is primarily used for firewalls, and it is not designed to do load balancing.
> However, you could craft a smart set of rules that could make `iptables` behave like a load balancer.
> And this is precisely what happens in Kubernetes.
>
> If you have three Pods, `kube-proxy` writes the following rules:
>
> - select Pod 1 as the destination with a likelihood of 33%. Otherwise, move to the next rule
> - choose Pod 2 as the destination with a probability of 50%. Otherwise, move to the following rule
> - select Pod 3 as the destination (no probability)
>
> **What happens when you use keep-alive with a Kubernetes Service?**
>
> Let's imagine that front-end and backend support keep-alive.
> You have a single instance of the front-end and three replicas for the backend.
> The front-end makes the first request to the backend and opens the TCP connection.
> The request reaches the Service, and one of the Pod is selected as the destination.
> The backend Pod replies and the front-end receives the response.
> But instead of closing the TCP connection, it is kept open for subsequent HTTP requests.
> What happens when the front-end issues more requests?
> They are sent to the same Pod.
>
> **Isn't iptables supposed to distribute the traffic?**
> It is.
> There is a single TCP connection open, and iptables rule were invocated the first time.
> One of the three Pods was selected as the destination.
> Since all subsequent requests are channelled through the same TCP connection, `iptables` isn't invoked anymore.

Also it's not quite correct to say that ***kube-proxy is in the middle***.
It isn't - `kube-proxy` by itself doesn't manage any traffic.
All that it does - it creates iptables rules.
It's `iptables` who actually listens, distributes, does DNAT etc.

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64876107/kubernetes-requests-not-balanced).

Comment: Does [IPVS proxy mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#proxy-mode-ipvs) load balance requests, or is that also just load balancing connections, resulting in the same "sticky" situation above?

Comment: From what I've read, IPVS is an L4 load balancer, so it load balances TCP connections, not HTTP requests. So IPVS would not help in this case.

Comment: if you want to have control over the intra service traffic in your cluster, better to take look to istio